# Map with condition in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to make a mapping to an array with a function but only is a condition is fullfilled. For my particular problem I have an array of objects and only want to do a function on a sub-array of this big array.

```
function :: a -> a

mapping :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
mapping all sub = map (\x -> if (x `elem` sub) then function x else x) all
```

how can I do something like this ?

edit: I know this code works but in my class this is considered bad design and we need to avoid using if statements and need to use guards and such instead.

Comment: Your example is legal Haskell code. What exactly is your problem? That is, what about the solution you already have doesn’t work?

Comment: do you want this: mapping p f xs= map (\x-> if p x then f x else x) xs

Comment: well the code I have now is considered bad design in my class, we need to try to avoid if and use guards and such instead

Comment: I'd not consider that bad design at all. Still, if you want to use guards you can use ``mapping all sub = map f all where f x | x `elem` sub = function x | otherwise = x``, giving a name for the function you `map`

Comment: Note that you are working with lists, and not arrays. This isn't just terminology nitpicking; it is important to keep the difference in mind as you learn to work with Haskell lists.

Comment: Letting `sub` be the first argument would make this cleaner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part that seems like bad design to me is that you fail to factor out the basic pattern. As [assembly.jc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7940614/assembly-jc) has [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53250487/map-with-condition-in-haskell#comment93385914_53250487), you should really give that its own function.

```
mapOnly :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapOnly p f = map $ \x -> if p x then f x else x
```

Using `if` seems quite reasonable style in this context; anything else really comes off as clunky.

Answer (score 0):

If you are force to use guards, is pretty straightforward. I think `if .. then .. else` is a good pattern here though. As @dfeuer says, include the predicate and the function in `mapping`'s signature.

```
mapping :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapping _ _ []     = []
mapping p f (a:as)
  | p a       = f a: mapping p f as
  | otherwise = a:mapping p f as
```